# Converting a string with a mixture of upper and lower case characters java

Tags: java

Below is my code. Basically it worksout whether the characters are in ascending or descending order. It works perfectly if a lower case word is entered, but if for example aB is entered it is saying the letters are not in orde, when they clearly are!!! not really to sure and i'm starting to dispair at this!

```
    text.toLowerCase();

    while ( ! text.equals( "END" ) ) 

    {       

        String string = (text);
        char[] content = string.toCharArray();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(content);
        String sorted = new String(content);          


            if (text.equals(sorted))
            {
                System.out.print(text);
                System.out.print("     letters in ascending order");
                System.out.println();

            }

            else           
            {
                System.out.print((text));
                System.out.print("    letters not in ascending order");
                System.out.println();
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print( "#Enter input text : " );
            text = BIO.getString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to save the value back to `text` (and check for a lower-case `"end"` since it was converted).

```
text = text.toLowerCase();
while (!text.equals("end")) { // ...
```

`toLowerCase` does not modify the original string, rather returns a lower-cased version.

Alternatively, if you want to preserve `"END"` to end:

```
lowered = text.toLowerCase();
while (!text.equals("END")) { 
    // ... etc ...
    text = BIO.getString();
    lowered = text.toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `text.compareToIgnoreCase(sorted) == 0` ?